# Pytorch softmax along different masks without for loop

Tags: parallel-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, softmax, attention-model

Say I have a vector `a` , with an index vector `b` of the same length. The indexs are in range 0~N-1, corresponding to N groups. How can I do softmax for every group without for loop?

I'm doing some sort of attention operation here. The numbers for every group are not the same, so I can't reshape `a` to a matrix and use the `dim` in standard `Softmax()` API.

Toy example:

```
a = torch.rand(10)
a: tensor([0.3376, 0.0557, 0.3016, 0.5550, 0.5814, 0.1306, 0.2697, 0.9989, 0.4917,
        0.6306])
b = torch.randint(0,3,(1,10), dtype=torch.int64)
b: tensor([[1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

I want to do softmax like

```
for index in range(3):
    softmax(a[b == index])
```

but without the for loop to save time.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but what you are looking for is not a softmax, but a element-wise mean squared error, right?
Since your computation for softmax would assume that the total sum of values along the main axis in `a` would sum to 1.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Acutally I'm not computing a loss here. The indices in `b` are more proper to be considered as groups rather than classes. I want a softmax probability of every **scaler** in `a` that belong to the same indice, them use these probabilities as weights for later computation. Thus the output for every indice sum to 1, in the N groups example, the output summation should be N.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer will have to change slightly based on a potential response to my comment, but I'm just going ahead and throwing in my two cents about `Softmax`.

Generally, the formula for softmax is explained rather well in the [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=softmax#torch.nn.functional.softmax), where we can see that this is a exponential of the current value, divided by the sum of all classes. 
The reason for doing this is founded in probability theory, and probably a little outside of my comfort zone, but essentially it helps you to maintain a rather simple backpropagation derivative, when using it in combination with a popular loss strategy called "Cross Entropy Loss" (CE) (see the corresponding function in PyTorch [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=softmax#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss).

Furthermore, you can also see in the description for CE that it *automatically combines two functions*, namely a (numerically stable) version of the softmax function, as well as the negative log likelihood loss (NLLL).

Now, to tie back to your original question, and hopefully resolving your issue:
For the sake of the question - and the way you asked it - it seems you are playing around with the popular MNIST handrwitten digit dataset, in which we want to predict some values for your current input image.

I am also assuming that your output `a` will at some point be the output from a layer from a neural network. It does not matter whether this is squashed to a specific range or not (e.g., by applying some form of activation function), as the softmax will be basically a normalization. Specifically, it will give us, as discussed before, some form of distribution across all the predicted values, and sum up to 1 across all classes. To do this, we can simply apply something like

```
soft_a = softmax(a, dim=0) # otherwise throws error if we don't specify axis
print(torch.sum(soft_a)) # should return "Tensor(1.)"
```

Now, if we assume that you want to do the "classical" MNIST example, you could then use the `argmax()` function to predict which value your system thinks is the correct answer, and calculate an error based off that, e.g., with the `nn.NLLLoss()` function.

If you are indeed predicting values for *each position in a single output*, you have to think slightly different about this.
First of all, `softmax()` ceases to make sense here, since you are computing a probability distribution *across multiple outputs*, and unless you are fairly certain that their distributions are dependent on one another in a very specific way, I would argue that this is not the case here.

Also, keep in mind that you are then looking to calculate a pairwise loss, i.e. something for every index of your output. The function that comes to mind for this specific purpose would be [`nn.BCELoss()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=softmax#torch.nn.BCELoss), which calculates a binarized (element-wise) version of Cross-Entropy.
For this, you can then simply "prop in" your original prediction tensor `a`, as well as your ground truth tensor `b`. A minimal example for this would look like this:

```
bce = torch.nn.BCELoss(reduction="none") # to keep losses for each element separate
loss = bce(a,b) # returns tensor with respective pairwise loss
```

If you are interested in a single loss, you can obviously use `BCELoss` with a different argument for `reduction`, as described in the docs.
Let me know if I can clarify some parts of the answer for you.

EDIT: Something else to keep in mind here: The `BCELoss()` requires you to feed in values that can potentially be close to the value you want to predict. This is especially a problem if you feed in values to an activation function first (e.g., sigmoid or tanh), which can then *never reach* the value you want to predict, since they are bound by an interval!

Comment: Thanks for replying, I left a comment below the question. Maybe I should put my question more clearly. By the way, shouldn't the **taget** for `BCELoss()` be only 0 or 1?